# Build Network performance using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, performance, network-analyst, network-dataset

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and have access to the Network Analyst extension. I'm new to the Network Analyst tools and I have been following the [Create A Network Dataset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/analysis/networks/how-to-create-a-usable-network-dataset.htm) tutorial using my own data. I have followed almost of all of the steps, with the exception that I only have driving as my travel mode. My roads feature class contains approximately 19000 features. Service-Area Index has been turned on. After I have create the network dataset, I've been attempting to build the network using "Build Network". However, this process has taken over 48hrs and the progress bar is showing 2%. I have received no errors so far and the application does not appear to be stalling.

If this is not normal, how long does it generally take to build a network?

Comment: That depends on the volume of data involved.

Comment: Thanks for your response Vince! I was concerned that I wasn't seeing any movement at all, but I suppose my dataset is probably on the large side and that's why it's taking awhile.

Comment: Lots of variables, too.  How much RAM and speed of local disk are critical.

Comment: That might be where the issue is. I'm writing to and my data is coming from a network drive. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Network disk access is 10x, 100x, 1000x, maybe even 10000x times slower than local SSD.  You could be on pace for a 1000 day operation.